# Is it possible, using htaccess to load a CSS file for any file opened within that directory by default?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am hoping to have each image file opened within a certain directory ('example.com/image.jpg') to load a css file so I can make the image load at 100% width.

**Edit**: To be clear, I am aware that I would have to do this by loading an HTML file with CSS inside, my real question is how do I target the files inside with the CSS styling, instead of the directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a Rewrite rule from your htaccess to load them through a HTML file where you'll be able to specify a CSS?  A picture on its own cannot use CSS.

A solution would be to a) move your pictures somewhere they can be accessed but not directly in the path the user will access, b) create a php file (or other) that passes the parameter from the htaccess to some HTML content and c) create an htaccess that does the redirection unless you're directly accessing the folder where the actual file is located, otherwise you'll have an infinite loop of redirections

I therefore created 2 files: fullscreen.php and .htaccess. I then created a folder named /img/ where the images reside.

I kept fullscreen.php as simple as possible, feel free to improve on the style!

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['img']))
{
    $imageParam = $_GET['img'];
    echo "<html><head><style>html { background: url($imageParam) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; }</style></head><body></body></html>";
}
else
{
    echo "Image not provided";
}
```

Then in .htaccess I added a rewrite rule that has a condition - do not process the rule if the path contains /img/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/
    RewriteRule ^(.*).png$ fullscreen.php?img=/img/$1.png [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I believe this is what you were looking for?

Comment: This was actually more inline with what I was hoping to find out how to do. I worded the initial question pretty poorly. I attempted to load in an HTML file which contained CSS but I couldn't seem to figure out how to target the files in the directory. The css kept targeting the styling of the actual directory page.